# edit cell of the table in pug and save edited data into data base

Tags: javascript, mongodb, pug

I have a table created using pug or jade, I wish to edit the cell of my table and save the edited to data to the data base.

```
    div(class="",style="max-width:60%;display:flex;flex-flow:row wrap;flex-basis:auto;")
    -var columnList = ["Source", "Keyword", "Status", "Description"]

    div(class="tbl_")
      div(class="tblHeader_ fourColumn_")
        each item in columnList
          div(class="tblCell_") #{item}
      div(class="tblBody_")
        each keyword in keywords
          div(class="tblRow_ fourColumn_")
            div(class="tblCell_") #{keyword.Source}
            div(class="tblCell_") #{keyword.Keyword}
            if keyword.Status == 0
              div(class="tblCell_") None
            else if keyword.Status == 1
              div(class="tblCell_") Data Collection
            else if keyword.Status == 2
              div(class="tblCell_") Data Processing
            else if keyword.Status == 3
              div(class="tblCell_")DataCollecton/Processing
            div(class="tblCell_") #{keyword.Description}



    $(function () {
      $(".inner").dblclick(function (e) {
        if($(event.target).attr('class')!="thVal") {
          e.stopPropagation();
          var currentEle = $(this);
          var value = $(this).html();
          updateVal(currentEle, value);
        }
      });
    });

    function updateVal(currentEle, value) {
      $(document).off('click');
      $(currentEle).html('<input class="thVal" type="text" value="' + value + '"/>');
      $(".thVal").focus();
      $(".thVal").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
          $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val());
        }
      });

      $(document).click(function () {
        if($(event.target).attr('class')!="thVal") {
          $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val());
          $(document).off('click');
        }
      });
    }
```

I tried the above js code but of no use and I also provided table code in pug ,please provide me the correct java script code that can edit the cell of the table and saves the edited data to the data base.

Comment: But there's no "above code", only a Pug template. Please add it to your question (click "edit")

Comment: I have added the java script code , Please provide me correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not much familiar with Pug but you can check jeditable JS for inline editing. It might work for you.

https://appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/